# How can I type in uppercase only in LibreOffice?

Tags: microsoft-office, formatting, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I know that I can use Format -> Text -> Case in LibreOffice to change text to uppercase when it is selected afterwards, but I would like to type directly in uppercase all the time, without having to press the Caps Lock key on my keyboard (because then I cannot type numbers on the top row of my keyboard).

In Microsoft Office, it is possible to select capital letters as a general preset for text. Is there a similar feature in LibreOffice, and where can I find it?

Comment: "because then I cannot type numbers on the top row of my keyboard" - your keyboard types `!"£$%^&*()` instead of `1234567890` when CAPS LOCK is on?

Comment: What language is your keyboard? French AZERTY keyboards have numbers on the shift key instead of unshifted. This behaviour hangs over into the CapsLock key too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/81lox.png Just about all other input languages, you can just use CapsLock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this tutotial](https://www.howtogeek.com/278064/how-to-easily-change-the-case-of-text-in-libreoffice-writer/) about how to change the case of texts on Libre Office? I believe it contains a solution for you, with plenty of details.

In summary - you can use `shift + f3` to switch case of the selected text. Also, in the toolbar, head to Format > Text > Change Case > tOGGLE cASE (or whichever case option you want). And, finally, if you wish other options, then, select “Character” from the “Format” menu, on the Character dialog box, click the “Font Effects” tab and select an option from the “Effects” drop-down list.

I hope this helps you...